# Call api after bage build in getx

Tags: flutter-getx

Im using getx and i want to call api after bage build, because this api its not necessary part of the page build.. What i know is this way

```js
@override
void initState(){
  super.initState();
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
   
  });
  
}
```

**But what about getx best way ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `Getx` package offers lifecycle methods that are very convenient in you're cases, what you need here is to use the `onReady()`, which is called one frame after the `onInit()` is executed, you can say that its equivalent to the:

```
   @override
    void initState(){
      super.initState();
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){  
    // Here is the code which will be executed exactly after initState using StatefulWidget
      });          
    }
```

you can use `onReady()` like this:

```
 class TextController extends GetxController {
 @override
  void onInit() {
   /*...*/
  }
  void onReady() {
   // Here is the code which will be executed exactly after onInit using Getx
  }
}
```